# Bug Tracker Link on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, comments

A number of issues found on SO are bugs in the discussed software, libraries, API's, etc. Most of this software has public bug tracking and reporting systems, and when a bug is identified on SO, it would be helpful to mark a quick link to the noted bug tracker's id. Right now, I only find it in comments, and some comments are out of date. A dedicated "bug-tracker" link field would be useful and could be updated over time to reflect the live bug. Is there any way to do that now other than in comments?

Answer (score 6):

You (or anyone, really) could always edit the link directly into the question or answer where it matters.

The effect would be about the same as editing a dedicated field, assuming that's what you mean by "updated over time". (Actually trying to poll whatever public bug trackers may be out there for status sounds like more effort than it's worth.)

Editing would be my recommendation in general - if you see something in the comments that's important and relevant to the answer, *edit it in*. And if you're about to leave a comment with relevant information, also consider editing it into the post directly so others can benefit without hunting through comments.